# Excluding Mobile UI from look script, Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, mobile

While building for mobile and PC I've run into issues implementing look scripts that don't interact with UI elements such as a mobile joystick. They created a new input system to manage this and every tutorial seems to have parts of this but never includes other parts that I need. Like perfectly showcases controls but no look script, or has both perfectly but doesn't work with the new input system.

This has been a nightmare, I am not a professional coder, I don't claim to know anything and I have tried reaching out on C# Discord without even being noticed for 2 weeks so I just left. Hopefully someone comes across this some day and sends help.

I will update this if I find a way through it. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Hi there! So, you have look script but that script also works when you move the joystick? If so then you need to create a UI panel or just a transparent image and add onpointerdown or onpointerswipe event using event trigger and call your "look" function as an event. May I see your look script, so I can help you further?

Comment: Thank you, Currently handing it off to someone else. I believe we will just use the dual joysticks instead then set a handling event at the start to delegate which interface to use. This way we can move forward and not worry about taking so long.